# Get formatted date in string format in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using the following LINQ to Entities code for getting data from a database table named `Stocks`:

```
IEnumerable<DrugInfoViewModel> Info = from a in db.Stocks.Where(
   r => r.SiteID == SiteID 
        && r.MachineID == MachineID 
        && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.ExpiryDate) <= ExpiryDate)
   select new DrugInfoViewModel()
   {
        ItemName = a.DrugBrand.Name,                           
        ItemBatchNo = a.BatchNo,
        ItemExpiryDate = (a.ExpiryDate == null ? null :
          Convert.ToDateTime(a.ExpiryDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")),
                       Quantity = (int?)a.Qty
   };
```

Here, `ItemExpiryDate` is a string field and `a.ExpiryDate` is a nullable `datetime` field in the table. When I run this code I am getting this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

This same line of code works properly in another page. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why can't you format date at server side?

Comment: Or ideally, only format it *when you need to* - just before presenting. Keep it as a `DateTime` for as much of the time as you can.

Comment: Additionally - why are you using a query expression for select, but calling Where with a lambda expression? That's an odd mixture of styles for no obvious reason.

Comment: EF tries to translate everything between `Info =` and `;` into SQL. There's not translation support for `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` (neither `Convert.ToDateTime`). The other page works on objects in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the LINQ expression is evaluated on the server side i.e. inside SQL Server and there the function `ToString()` is not available.

As suggested in the comments already: Get a `DateTime`, format on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `ToList()` or `ToArray()` method after `Where()`. This will fetch filtered objects to your memory and you will be able to call `ToString()`. Please, make sure that you call `ToList()` **after** filtering to avoid fetching all of the records from the table.

```
IEnumerable<DrugInfoViewModel> Info = from a in db.Stocks.Where(
   r => r.SiteID == SiteID 
        && r.MachineID == MachineID 
        && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.ExpiryDate) <= ExpiryDate)
   .ToList()
   select new DrugInfoViewModel()
   {
        ItemName = a.DrugBrand.Name,                           
        ItemBatchNo = a.BatchNo,
        ItemExpiryDate = (a.ExpiryDate == null ? null :
          Convert.ToDateTime(a.ExpiryDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")),
                       Quantity = (int?)a.Qty
   };
```